# How to add all li of existing ul to the bottom of another ul base on their css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a site responsive and I need to merge two different menus. To do so I need to add all li of an ul to a different ul.

Here is a simplification of current markup I have:

```
<ul class="navigation-menu">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav-bar">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

I need to add all li of nav-bar to the bottom of the list of ul with class navigation-menu and then prevent nav-bar from being displayed in the browser.

Here is my attempt:

```
$('ul.nav-bar li').each(function() {
   $(this).after('ul.nav-bar:last-child');
}
```

Not sure how to tackle this one. I'll appreciate if some one can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `appendTo()` which will add the items to the bottom of `.navigation-menu`:

```
$('ul.nav-bar li').each(function() {
  $(this).appendTo('ul.navigation-menu');
});
```

And you can use media queries to hide the other div at a certain screen width (although it will be "hidden" because it will be empty):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px //example){
  .nav-bar{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

or JS if you prefer, but no reason to use JS when you can use CSS:

```
$('ul.nav-bar').hide();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t7dukrgu/1/)

**Update**

As vladkras pointed out you can shorten the JS to simply be:

```
$('ul.nav-bar li').appendTo('ul.navigation-menu');
```

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t7dukrgu/3/)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about doing it this way.

Comment: `each -> function() -> $(this)` is so excessive `$('ul.nav-bar li').appendTo('ul.navigation-menu');` will do exactly the same: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/t7dukrgu/2/)  Do you see something about CSS, or how to hide elements depending on screen resolution, or question about media queries? Me not.

Comment: Good point. I updated my post, although I wouldn't exactly call iterating over 3 items "so excessive", but it's not necessary, I agree.

Answer (score -1):

Hello here is example [Example](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/PwGxPX)

All you need is to clone list elements and append them after existing second menu :)

```js
$(function(){
  var children = $(".nav-bar li").clone();
    $(".navigation-menu").append(children);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation-menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav-bar">
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

And hide element for example on breakpoint 769px

```
@media screen and (max-width:769px){
    .nav-bar{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think OP needs to clone them. The question seems to be about how to move them and hide useless <ul>

Comment: I think its 100% OP , Read properly he want to add element li from one menu to another - merge and hide second one (which i missed)

Comment: **prevent from being displayed in the browser** always ment `hide()` where did you get this number `769px` from?!

Comment: I add media queries for helping about responsive design with hiding one of menu. And 769 it was example for random breakpoint - really learn to read. And from where did you get this "prevent from being displayed in the browser " always meant hide() wtf? display none = hide()... srsly what an...I did prevented to show menu, in my anwser in specific width which is good, after all he said "responsive" right?

Answer (score -1):

```
var navBar = $('.nav-bar'),
    LIs = navBar.children('li');
$('.navigation-menu').append(LIs);
navBar.hide(); // or .remove() if you don't need it anymore
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/n1cb8cmh/)